# Android Custom View with a Path drawn hit test

Tags: android

I am creating an Android application that allows free drawing.

The drawing area is represented by a FrameLayout that contains a set of DrawingView (derived from View).

Each DawingView has a transparent background and their size match the size of the FrameLayout.

The DrawingView draws a Path (built by calling path.moveTo followed by multiple path.lineTo)

```
 Path _penPath;
 Paint _paint;

@Override 
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     canvas.drawPath(_penPath, _paint);
}
```

I need to perform hit test that is true only if the touch pointer is on the actual path and false if it is on the transparent background.

Currently the onTouch function gets invoked for every DrawingView in the Z order sequence.

I know I could calculate the distance between the touch pointer and each point in the path and compare it with a threshold value to implement hit test but I hope there is something in the framework that I can use.

For example in C# WPF transparent areas don't raise touch events if not configured explicitly.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Claudiu, I am trying to solve a similar problem. The way I did it was by putting all these paths on a single view and then manage hit tests computations. Did you find a better solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did the same thing calculate the distance between the touch pointer and each point on the path.